# WSO2 EMM Server Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am very new to WSO2 and trying to use it. I downloaded wso2emm-2.2.0 . I tried running wso2server.bat start

But getting error :
 Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

D:\Software\WSO2\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin>wso2server.bat
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to D:\Software\jdk1.8.0_25
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to D:\Software\WSO2\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin..
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
D:\Software\WSO2\wso2emm-2.2.0\bin>

Comment: What is the windows version you are having?

Comment: windows 10 and jdk 1.8

Comment: It seems this is a bug when running against windows 8 it is reported at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1856

Comment: so its bug we cant go with windows 10

Comment: This issue is now fixed in IoT 3.1.0 release [1] https://github.com/wso2/product-iots/issues/596